# rotation & translate value when draw text to line(x1, y1, x2, y2) (use p5.js, processing ... atan2)

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

when I draw text to line, and rotate with theta
the text is very far from line.
I think, the cause is rely on the translate, but I don't know how to fix it.
this is my code (p5.js)

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 700);
    
    x = 100;
    y = 200;
    x2 = 300;
    y2 = 500;
}

function draw() {
    background(200);

    strokeWeight(2);
    stroke(0, 255, 0);
    line(x, y, x2, y2);

    strokeWeight(5);
    stroke(255, 0, 0)
    point(x, y);
    point(x2, y2);
    textSize(10);
    noStroke();
    text(`x(${x}, ${y})`, x, y);
    text(`x(${x2}, ${y2})`, x2, y2);

    // Whether this code needs "translate" or not,
    // I want to know same method when I draw text to line, circle ... so on
    translate(x, y);
    rotate(atan2(y2 - y, x2 - x));

    noStroke();
    textSize(50);
    fill(0, 0, 255);

    text("A", x, y);
    rect(x, y, 50, 50);
}
```

[image]

I want to fix the text fit to line closely

[image]

I've been struggling this question for five days.
after hardly grasping about theta and tangent, and so on,
staying this step is makes me impatient of next step... please help!

Comment: Note: I find the easiest method when placing text is to translate to a point on the line (not the x,y start point), then apply rotation, then place the text it at "0,0" because the position is already set by the translate and rotate. You will need to do a bit of trigonometry to work out the distance down the line that you need to go to get x and y co-ordinates for translate.

Comment: you saved me, thank you very much! text("A", 0, 0,) works!

Comment: @sorifiend you should post that as an answer so it can be voted/accepted/easily spotted by others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea here for placing text is that you want to translate to an exact point on the line/shape, then rotate and place your text, for example, you could do the following to place rotated text at the start of the line:

```
//Translate to the start of the line
translate(x, y);
//rotate to the desired angle (for example 20)
rotate(20);
//place the text at the start of the line
text("A", 0, 0);
```

If you want the text to be at a specific point along the line/shape you can perform some trigonometry to find the exact point, and then use those points for the translate:

```
//Translate to a point on the line before you rotate
translate(linePointX, linePointY);
//rotate to the desired angle (for example 20)
rotate(20);
//place the text at 0,0 (the point of the last translate)
//or increase/decrease the x and y vaues to offset the text
text("A", 0, 0);
```